# Can I pass address type to bytes32 type?

Tags: solidity

It looks like sometimes address can be accepted for bytes32 type argument.
Is implicit conversion possible?

Comment: You can try it on your own in remix.ethereum.org

Answer (score 3):

It was *implicitly* convertible in older versions of the compiler.

```
address a = bytes32(0);
```

It is *explicitly* convertible through `uint160` in recent versions of the compiler.

```
address a = address(uint160(uint(bytes32(0))));
```

In both cases, it is a truncating conversion.

In case parsing that expression is a little cryptic.

**bytes32 => uint256** is a non-truncating change of type casting, to unsigned integer

**uint256 => uint160** is an allowable, truncating conversion that reduces it to 20 bytes

**uint160 => address** is a non-truncating change of type casting, to address

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is it also possible to do something like this?
bytes32 sample = 0x000... (address type)

Comment: In reverse `bytes32 b = bytes32(uint256(uint160(address(0x0000...))));`